# how to show bar chart for every product

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm trying to print a bar chart for every product to show a summary of data but the bar chart is showing only once with different values at y-axis.

How can I show the data for each product on a bar chart?

**Review.js**

```
angular.module('App.review',[]).directive('review', function($cookieStore){
return{
     restrict:'E',
     controller:function($scope, $window, $http){
             var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
             var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                 type: 'horizontalBar',
                 data: {
                     labels: ["Rating", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "O"],
                     datasets: [{
                         label: '# of Votes',
                         data: $scope.data,
                         backgroundColor: [
                             'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                         ],
                         borderColor: [
                             'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                             'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                             'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                             'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                             'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                             'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                         ],
                         borderWidth: 1
                     }]
                 },
                 options: {
                     scales: {
                         xAxes: [{                
                             display: false,
                             stacked: false,
                             ticks: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    max: 10
                                }
                         }]
                     }
                 }
             });
            },
     templateUrl:'scripts/directives/ReviewDirective/review.html',
     transclude:false
}
 });
```

**review.html**

```
<div style="width:100%; border:solid green;">
 <canvas  id="myChart" width="100" height="100vh"></canvas>
</div>
```

**product.html**

```
<td ng-controller="ReviewsCtrl" >
              <div data-ng-repeat="r in dataList" >
                <div data-ng-if=" r.id == item.productId">
                  <div data-ng-init="data =r.data" > 
                    {{data=r.data}}
                    <review></review>
                  </div>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </td>
```

Comment: Can you share the plugins name used for bar chart?

Comment: I used chart.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code

```js
 var app = angular.module('App.review', []);

    app.directive('review', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: "=data"
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                var ctx = element[0].querySelector('#myChart');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'horizontalBar',
                    data: {
                        labels: ["Rating", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "O"],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: '# of Votes',
                            data: $scope.data,
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                display: false,
                                stacked: false,
                                ticks: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    max: 10
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            templateUrl: 'review.html',
            transclude: false
        }
    });
    app.controller('ReviewsCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dataList = [{
            productId: 1,
            productName: 'One',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }, {
            productId: 2,
            productName: 'Two',
            data: [6, 7, 8, 1, 1]
        }];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App.review">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td ng-controller="ReviewsCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="r in dataList">
     {{r.productName}}
     <review data="r.data"></review>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="review.html">
  <div style="width: 100%; border: solid green;">
   <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100vh"></canvas>
  </div>
 </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Finally working. Thank you very much, I've spent the day trying to get it to work but I'm still learning.